# Form groups based on consecutive values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table with users and their timestamps showing when they had their activity. In order to calculate streak (consecutive rows per user with no gaps or one day gap) I added a row number and subtract that from the timestamp, which gives me one cohort.
Now my table looks like this. What I would like to achieve is to merge the groups that have only 1 day difference between them.

So:

```
1. 2022-10-30 -- 2022 -11-10 = Streak days 11
2. 2022-11-13 -- 2022-11-15 = Streak days 2
```

I tried something like this:

```sql
case 
  when lead(grp,1) over(partition by UserID order by grp) is null then 1
  when DATE_DIFF(grp,lag(grp,1) over(partition by UserID order by grp),DAY) = 1 then 1
  else 0 
end AggregateGroup
from tmp
```

But it doesn't count in a row if a do a min/max afterwards.

Comment: you could do this in the first step: `select date_diff(date_col, lead(date_col) over (partition by userid order by grp))<2` for "Streak at least every 2nd days"

Comment: SQL Server is not the same thing as Google BigQuery - please correct your tags.